# Facing Recv failure: Connection was reset on azure classic and YAML Pipeline after migrating from Azure Repos to GitHub Repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So the scenario is.

Someone in our team has created a pipeline to run TestComplete scripts inside a self hosted agent in AzureDevOps, after the repo migration, this pipeline has been failing with "Recv failure: Connection was reset" error.

I am fairly new to yaml

Is there any way out of this, I'm stuck at a dead end here.

Things I have tried:

1. setting value for checkout: none -> added custom script to clone repo and checkout master branch
   error: git is not a recognizable command (something like this)
   but I have already installed git in the self hosted agent and verified the installation
2. using persistCredentials key in self checkout section, still seeing the same Connection was reset error.

Expectation is for it to successfully checkout the repo's master branch.

P.S - We have other pipelines which are running absolutely fine under these same circumstances, the only difference is, they are running in Azure Pipelines' agent in ubuntu-latest.
Also, this was working fine for before migrating to GitHub repositories.

[Here's a screenshot of that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beNC3.png)

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please try: 1. Run your affected pipeline on MS-hosted agent, (for example, ubuntu-latest) and check if it has the same error or not. 2. Please check if you can clone your GitHub repo on your local machine, which is set up as self-hosted agent. 3. If it's convenient, please run the affected pipeline on a new self-hosted agent and check the result. Based on theses, we can know if the issue is related to the pipeline or your local environment. 4. After migrating the repo, do you re-create the pipeline based on the GitHub repo or modify the old pipeline?

Comment: I did try to run the pipeline on MS hosted agent (ubuntu-latest) and it worked fine. Come to think of it, the hosted machine is probably not able to authenticate with GitHub, it is not feasible for us to change the hosted machine so I am going to clone the git repo into the already running self hosted agent and check what's the deal there. Will update here

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Nautiyal, what's the latest state of the issue? Based on your last comment, I agree that the self-hosted agent may can't authenticate with GitHub.  You can try to clone the GitHub repo directly on that affected machine and check what's the result.

Comment: Yes, so the issue was the hosted agent was not able to communicate with git, we established git secrets and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause was - The self-hosted windows machine was not able to communicate with GitHub. (error can differ from scenario to scenario)

Solution - Set git credentials on the self hosted system, through Control panel -> generic credentials.

Test out the setup by cloning the repo in the system manually through command prompt.